# How to write Java unit test with simulated time in Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-storm

I have got Storm topology that computes aggregations for each minute.
I would like to cover the application by Java unit test but I am not able to 
find any working example of some Java unit test.

I need to simulute changes in time, get output of topology and test it.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/mjsax/aeolus/tree/master/queries/lrb/src/test/java/de/hub/cs/dbis/lrb/operators

Comment: Thanks. The tests are testing each bolt separately. I would like to test entire topology in one test. I think it requires using "Testing" class.

Comment: Did you try using `LocalCluster`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be:

```
Testing.withSimulatedTimeLocalCluster(new TestJob() {
    public void run(Cluster cluster) {
        // your testing logic here.
        Time.advanceTime(100);
    }
});
```

which exploits the `Testing` class (missing from all Javadocs inexplicably) together with the [`Time`](https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/storm/utils/Time.html) class and its helpful manual time advancement methods.

Note though that this will only help you with Storm's internal clock used for things like sliding windows etc. You own code needs to be aware of the simulated time as well. Standard ways to do that in the Java world include the [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class (Java 8 only) or the [`DateTimeUtils`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html) class if you're stuck with Joda-Time.